# Running a continuous running worker process on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

What is the best way for running a continuous worker process on Heroku? My application needs this process running 24/7, so delayed_job or other queues seem like overkill. I can trigger the process manually through the Heroku console, and I could detach it would run by itself.

Preferably, I'd like to assign just this single method call to a dyno, such that when my app boots, it launches the extra worker-dyno and then calls my single method and starts humming away. But not sure how to assign that method call?

I could use delayed job and it would solve everything, but it seems my need is for a singularly activity that is immediate (when called) and not scheduled. But perhaps this is the only way.

Comment: Could you give an example what this long-running process might do?

Comment: @ThomasKlemm This is a server status application, so the process is monitoring multiple applications and making frequent HTTP requests.

Comment: Frequent HTTP requests might make you opt for [Sidekiq](http://sidekiq.org/) as a background worker instead of delayed job, which might perform them in a non-blocking way when combined with a threadsafe HTTP client like [this special one](https://github.com/nahi/httpclient). That said, I'll post an answer below that might get more to the point of what you are looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your Procfile you could add a seperate process for your extra worker job

```
# Procfile
web: ...
worker: ...
collector: bundle exec ruby stats_collector.rb -p $PORT # or any other command
```

You could then scale this process with `$ heroku ps:scale collector=1`. It would run seperately and be stopped and restarted at every deploy. I'd say that what your app does thus has to be safe to be interrupted any time to use such a long running process.

If interruptions might lead to problem (e.g. stuff you want only done once is done twice if restarted) the a 'traditional' background worker using e.g. [Sidekiq](http://sidekiq.org) that queues messages might be a safer solution.

**Update**

If you want to execute long-running code non-interactively in the context of your Rails app, you can use the [**rails runner**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#rails-runner) command.

```
# Procfile
web: ...
worker: ...
collector: bundle exec rails runner 'MyModel.my_long_running_job'
```

Comment: I think this will work perfectly. My worker process can handle the multiple threads of HTTP requests, and this command, I think, is what I've been looking for!

Comment: Got the collector going, but struggling to get a Class.method to be called from within my app. Calling just a ruby.rb file (stats_collector in your example), only runs the code (not knowing any other classes) within that file, or am I missing something?

Comment: I think the update including `rails runner` can help you. Please report back if that made it work.

Comment: Never tried rails runner, and instead put the call into a rake task, which I used within collector. Debugging a Heroku worker is a challenge, but it now works like a charm. Thanks.

Comment: Can't find info about the collector process. Will it be killed after 24 hours as dynos are? I need to run a continuous process that runs longer than 24 hours.

Comment: @januszm The collector process here is just a dyno with a custom, non-standard process name. It will be treated as all dynos/processes are.