# Ruby : /app/bin/ruby: No such file or directory - Collector

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I have a rails app I'm running on Heroku.

There is a file that I need to constantly be running. I followed this [Running a continuous running worker process on Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12814867/running-a-continuous-running-worker-process-on-heroku)

In my procfile:

```
collector: bundle exec ruby flow.rb -p $PORT
```

When try to run the collector in Heroku, I get:

```
/app/bin/ruby: No such file or directory -- flow.rb (LoadError)
```

I have the flow.rb file inside my lib directory. Why am I getting this error? Where should I place the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass a full path to the executable file. If it in the lib directory

```
collector: bundle exec ruby ./lib/flow.rb -p $PORT
```